Configure OpenProject with two domains using Traefik and Docker
I'm setting up OpenProject in Docker with Traefik for reverse proxying. I need OpenProject to be accessible through two domains.
The primary domain is foo.local, where everything should work as usual.
The secondary domain is bar.local, through which users should be able to interact with OP as if they are using foo.local. OpenProject should treat requests from bar.local as if they were coming from foo.local and avoid redirecting to the primary domain.
I've encountered several issues with redirect loops and incorrect redirects when trying to set up access via both domains. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

When I don't set the Host header (...customrequestheaders.Host=foo.local), I get an Invalid host_name configuration error.

If I add only ...customrequestheaders.Host=foo.local, OpenProject redirects from bar.local to foo.local, which isn’t what I need.



I tried:
...customrequestheaders.Host=foo.local
...customresponseheaders.Location=bar.local

This results in an incorrect URL: http://bar.local/bar.local.
4.
I also attempted
...customrequestheaders.Host=foo.local
...redirectregex.regex=http://foo.local/(.*)
...redirectregex.replacement=http://bar.local/$$1

But this results in ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
How can I configure Traefik and OpenProject so that OpenProject remains accessible on both domains (foo.local and bar.local)? I want users on bar.local to experience the site as if they were on foo.local, without seeing the primary domain in the URL.
